# Where's the module files for the build-in Apache in Snow Leopard

Tags: apache, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I'm new to Mac OS X and I'm going to do some dev work under Snow Leopard.
I enabled the build-in apache and found things below in file etc/apache2/httpd.conf:

LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule bonjour_module     libexec/apache2/mod_bonjour.so

But I cannot find the "libexec" directory in my system, did I make something wrong?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The config files are in `/etc/apache2` and the modules live in `/usr/libexec/apache2`.

The paths in httpd.conf are relative to HTTPD_ROOT, which can be found be saying `httpd -V`.

Comment: Thanks.
I found "SERVER_CONFIG_FILE" is "/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf".
What's the difference between "/etc/apache2" and "/private/etc/apache2"? It seems they're just the same.

Comment: They are the same, /etc is a symlink to /private/etc

Comment: Is there something else needed to install a module ? Can we say that all modules present in this directory are already installed? I've seen videos where ppl install modules with some commands, thanks

Answer (score 3):

- Go to your Hard Disk Drive in Finder
- Press "Shift + Command + Point (.)"
  It will display Hidden folders.
- Go to "/usr/libexec/apache2"

Voila!

There are apache modules.

Comment: What's the opposite of "viola"? I have apache installed and when I restart it it gives no errors so I know the modules exist, but I have no /usr/libexec/apache2 folder.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually under /usr:

```
/usr/libexec
```